# I have a mongodb data response like the output below and want to group the results of the array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongodb data response like the output below and want to group the results of the array field `studentsTakingSubject` by the `dateStarted` and then a count of `studentId` in the corresponding month but all my efforts have not worked. Please I need help

```
{
  "data": {
    "getSubjectPerformanceAnalysis": [
      {
        "_id": "5f11d2f4a40eff3f6af5ac31",
        "teacherAssigned": "5ecfb15a6b60d08d688fd519",
        "subjectName": "English",
        "term": "third",
        "classId": "5ef9fbcbcd7361513a423393",
        "code": "Sub-686c0d",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-17T16:33:56.029Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T14:35:25.574Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "studentsTakingSubject": [
          {
            "_id": "5f2424c7da6c6c344362d633",
            "studentId": "5f1583c488fbd82308e86e37",
            "dateStarted": "2020-07-31T13:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T14:03:51.590Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-31T14:03:51.590Z"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5f242570da6c6c344362d636",
            "studentId": "5f11d1d0a40eff3f6af5ac2e",
            "dateStarted": "2020-07-31T13:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T14:06:40.298Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-31T14:06:40.298Z"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5f2426ffda6c6c344362d63d",
            "studentId": "5f199749aa89b14929b68c39",
            "dateStarted": "2020-06-19T13:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T14:13:19.580Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-31T14:13:19.580Z"
          },
          {
            "_id": "5f242c2df97301390dc90b3e",
            "studentId": "5f199749aa89b14929b68c39",
            "dateStarted": "2020-06-19T13:53:26.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T14:35:25.574Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-31T14:35:25.574Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need an output like this

````
[
      {
        "_id": "01",
        "count": 1
      },
    {
        "_id": "02",
        "count": 5
      },
    {
        "_id": "03",
        "count": 7
      },
    {
        "_id": "04",
        "count": 20
      }
    ]
    ```
````

Comment: Where does the _id:"01", 02 ,03 come from

Comment: its meant to be come from mongodb auto generated id but i just used that to show want i want.